# How to get the key of a multi diamentional select box using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on jQuery custom validation of Multidimensional select box. I'm trying to access name of the multidimensional select box element:

```
 <select id="start_time_195" class="myclass" name="start_time[195]">
```

Using the following code snippet:

```
$.validator.addMethod("my_method", function(value, element) {
    console.log(element.name);
}, "This text will be displayed as validation message.");
```

The console output is `start_time[195]`

But I want to get the key `195` out of the element name. Is there any direct way to get this value?

The alternate way I think is to use the `.split()` function, but that could be a bit lengthy process.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add the `159` index as a `data-*` attribute on the element and read that back when needed

Comment: I thought there is some direct step to read this value, however I have implemented this logic as this is better than using a split function. Thank you @RoryMcCrossan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add in data like @Rory McCrossan  suggested. You can add id in attribute like data-id = 195

   ```
   $(this).attr('data-id');
   ```
2. If you dont't want to do this then fetch it from the id

   ```
   var id =$(this).attr('id');
   getid = id.split("_");
   getid[2]  // this is your value
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Ish :). I accept 1st solution, in fact answered by Rory McCrossan.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var name = $("#start_time_195").attr("name");

    var patt = /\d+/g;

    var value = name.match(patt);

    alert(value);

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="start_time_195" class="myclass" name="start_time[195]"></select>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var name = $("#start_time_195").attr("name");

        var patt = /\d+/g;

        var value = name.match(patt);

        alert(value);

    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have not tried this but I guess even this would have worked for me. Thank you for the suggestion :)